# LyX menu font size too small

Tags: fonts, lyx, size

I am using LyX on Windows, but the font size of the user interface is so small that it is unreadable. Setting the icon size changes the icon, but not the font in the menus or on the buttons.

[image: drop down menu]

[image: dialog box]

Comment: Do you have a HiDPI display? I think there will be improvements on this regard when LyX 2.4.0 is released, but that's still a couple of months away.

Comment: thanks after uninstalling and reinstalling various versions i rebooted my laptop and that fixed it ugh

Answer (score 1):

Reboot solved a similar issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

According to [the Lyx documentation](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Fonts), you want to change Qt framework’s settings for the menu fonts, using `qtconfig` .